# FTS is slow when searched word appears frequently in rows

Tags: postgresql, full-text-search, postgresql-10

I have a `message` table with a `content` column indexed for full text search:

```
create index message_fts on message using GIN(to_tsvector('english', content));
```

The problem I have and that I'd like to understand is that searches involving frequent words are very slow.

Here's a normal fast enough query on a rare "word":

```
miaou=> explain analyze select count(*) from message where (to_tsvector('english', content) @@ to_tsquery('fajre'));
                               QUERY PLAN                                                                  
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Finalize Aggregate  (cost=16808.35..16808.36 rows=1 width=8) (actual time=6.565..6.565 rows=1 loops=1)
   ->  Gather  (cost=16808.13..16808.34 rows=2 width=8) (actual time=1.608..6.556 rows=3 loops=1)
         Workers Planned: 2
         Workers Launched: 2
         ->  Partial Aggregate  (cost=15808.13..15808.14 rows=1 width=8) (actual time=0.456..0.457 rows=1 loops=3)
               ->  Parallel Bitmap Heap Scan on message  (cost=293.28..15803.69 rows=1776 width=0) (actual time=0.453..0.453 rows=0 loops=3)
                     Recheck Cond: (to_tsvector('english'::regconfig, content) @@ to_tsquery('fajre'::text))
                     ->  Bitmap Index Scan on message_fts  (cost=0.00..292.22 rows=4262 width=0) (actual time=0.954..0.954 rows=0 loops=1)
                           Index Cond: (to_tsvector('english'::regconfig, content) @@ to_tsquery('fajre'::text))
 Planning time: 0.249 ms
 Execution time: 8.400 ms
(11 rows)
```

And here's a very slow query on a frequent term:

```
miaou=> explain analyze select count(*) from message where (to_tsvector('english', content) @@ to_tsquery('faire'));
NOTICE:  word is too long to be indexed
DETAIL:  Words longer than 2047 characters are ignored.
<other identical notices removed for clarity>                                            
                               QUERY PLAN                                                                        
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Finalize Aggregate  (cost=189901.34..189901.35 rows=1 width=8) (actual time=47192.053..47192.053 rows=1 loops=1)
   ->  Gather  (cost=189901.12..189901.33 rows=2 width=8) (actual time=47188.506..47192.042 rows=3 loops=1)
         Workers Planned: 2
         Workers Launched: 2
         ->  Partial Aggregate  (cost=188901.12..188901.13 rows=1 width=8) (actual time=47183.158..47183.158 rows=1 loops=3)
               ->  Parallel Bitmap Heap Scan on message  (cost=2012.04..188702.23 rows=79558 width=0) (actual time=72.503..47152.312 rows=66781 loops=3)
                     Recheck Cond: (to_tsvector('english'::regconfig, content) @@ to_tsquery('faire'::text))
                     Rows Removed by Index Recheck: 1329552
                     Heap Blocks: exact=12673 lossy=22516
                     ->  Bitmap Index Scan on message_fts  (cost=0.00..1964.30 rows=190940 width=0) (actual time=64.740..64.740 rows=200347 loops=1)
                           Index Cond: (to_tsvector('english'::regconfig, content) @@ to_tsquery('faire'::text))
 Planning time: 0.268 ms
 Execution time: 47199.290 ms
(13 rows)
```

It can be noticed that the index correctly finds the relevant records (200347 of them).

What should I fix or look at ? I'm especially surprised by the many notices I get when just querying, given that the matching information is already given by the index.

Comment: Your version of Postgres? (Always!)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your bitmap has grown too large to fit in `work_mem`, and so it has "gone lossy" where it records just the blocks that contains matches (for some blocks), and then needs to recheck each row in those blocks.

```
                 Rows Removed by Index Recheck: 1329552
                 Heap Blocks: exact=12673 lossy=22516
```

Doing this is slow.  Especially so because you are using a functional index, and so it has to re-parse `content` for each of those rows as the parsed form is not stored in the table.  (That re-parsing is also why you get the NOTICEs).

Increase `work_mem` so that it can hold the entire bitmap.

Comment: Thanks for this good and clear answer. For the record I did `set work_mem='86MB';`.